# Google App Engine: Inject page-dependent CSS

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, jinja2

My webapp has different several entity types with different templates for each.

I'd like to inject CSS into the HTML `<body>` depending on which page or entity type I am viewing.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Python function in Jinja to read the CSS from the datastore or your project directory.

You have to register this Python function for Jinja in your environment:

```
env.filters['readcss'] = readcss
```

To read the data from your project you can use:

```
def readcss(css_file_name):    

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'inlinecss', css_file_name)
    return file(path, 'rb').read())
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @voscausa. I'm confident that this is the right approach, since others are vouching for it. I'm not adept in Jinja. May I ask of you to tell me what topics I should read from the Jinja documentation to understand your answer fully?

Answer (score 0):

@voscausa's answer is pretty clean and straightforward. Go with **his** answer if your setup allows it!

Another way that quickly comes to mind:

Example Class of entity:

```
class Test(ndb.Expando):
   pass
```

You can get the Entity name easily eg:

```
test = Test()
class_name = test.__class__.__name__
```

On the Handler that serves/uses the Entity `Test` probably on the HEADER inject via templating your classname

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/{{ class_name }}.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers might ignore CSS defined in the HTML body.  Conventionally CSS belongs in the HTML head element.

That aside, if it's a matter of merely choosing between several static styles, leverage caches of CSS documents in browsers and proxy servers.  Vary only the stylesheet names in the HTML however your jinja says this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
```

If it's a matter of varying details within the stylesheet, cacheing will not occur and an external stylesheet reference would cause an additional browser request.  Inlining the CSS in the HTML would be better like this:

```
<style>
    div.style1 { display:none; }
</style>
```

A third way is to use JavaScript to alter CSS properties after the page has loaded.  This takes more programmer effort and might delay the appearance of the desired style, but has the potential to be more dynamic and interactive.  jQuery UI does this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to inline CSS into the HTML body, you could simply include it in the template, like so:

```
<style>
    {% include 'local/path/to/my/stylesheet.css' %}
</style>
```

If you would like to inline or link CSS in the `<head>` HTML element (where it belongs) and have some kind of template hierarchy you could go for something like the following:

Base template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <style>
        {% block style %}{% endblock %}
    </style>
    {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

Entity template:

```
{% extends 'path/to/base/template.html' %}

{# inline CSS #}
{% block style %}
body {
    background-color: green;
}
{% endblock %}

{# external CSS #}
{% block stylesheet %}
    <link href="/public/path/to/my/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
...
```

However, if the entity type only affects the HTML in that template, you could also use the entity name as CSS class and do the rest in one stylesheet using that class to differentiate between cases.